# Swift: Custom view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to build a cinema ticketing app and I need help with my view hierarchy. At the moment my cinemaView does not get added to the VC.

Here is how I attempt to do it. I have a custom seatView that has two properties (isVacant and seatNumber) and a custom cinemaView that has [seatView] as a property (well different cinema has different seatings). My code as such:

```
//In my viewController
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let cinema: CinemaView = {
       let v = CinemaView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let seat1 = SeatView()
        seat1.isVacant = false
        seat1.seatNumber = "2A"

        let seat2 = SeatView()
        seat2.isVacant = true
        seat2.seatNumber = "3B"
        cinema.seats = [seat1, seat2]

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(cinema)

        let views = ["scrollView": scrollView, "v": cinema]
        let screenHeight = view.frame.height

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView(\(screenHeight / 2))]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))

        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-60-[v(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))
        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))

    }

//At my custom cinemaView
class CinemaView: UIView {

    var seats = [SeatView]()
    var xPos: Int = 0

    let cinemaView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(cinemaView)
        cinemaView.backgroundColor = .black

        let views = ["v": cinemaView]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views))


        for seat in seats {
            cinemaView.addSubview(seat)
            seat.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
            xPos += 8 
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//At my custom seatView
class SeatView: UIView {
    var isVacant: Bool?
    var seatNumber: String?

    let seatView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(seatView)
        seatView.backgroundColor = setupBackgroundColor()

    }

    func setupBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        if let isVacant = isVacant {
            if isVacant {
                return UIColor.green
            } else {
                return UIColor.black
            }
        } else {
            return UIColor.yellow
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

My code does not seem to add the cinemaView to my VC. Could anyone point me where have I gone wrong? Or perhaps even advice if this method is suitable for this application? Thanks.

Comment: I think, It seems you have not added seat view to cinema view. You have added seat view in init method and set them afterward. So when you set the seatviews to cinema view, it simply adds the property and view is not added. I think you should create some function like addSeats(), and inside there, you add seat views inside cinema view and revalidate this view.

Comment: @Sunilluitel I thought I added in the `for seat in seats` liners, ie I did call `addSubview(seat)`

Comment: @Koh - do you want your Scroll View to be 1/2 the height of your main view? and then the "cinema" view inside that to be 60-pts from the top of the scroll view, 50-pts tall and fill the width of the scroll view?

Comment: @DonMag yes. I want the cinemaView to reside within my scrollView. The size of my cinemaView seem absurd now as I am testing it out, but I will change the size of the cinemaView subsequently to accommodate various cinema sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are doing several things wrong here...

1. You are subclassing `UIView`, but in your custom view you are adding a `UIView` as a subview, and trying to treat that as your actual view.
2. In your `CinemaView` class, you are looping your array of "seats" ... but you are doing so *before* assigning the array, so no seats will ever be created.
3. Similarly, in `SeatView`, you are trying to set the background color based on the `.isVacant` property, but you are doing so before the property is set.
4. You are trying to use a `UIScrollView` but you do not have the constraints set up correctly.
5. Setting constraints with Visual Format may feel convenient or easy, but it has limits. In your specific case, you want your scroll view to be 1/2 the height of your main view. With VFL, you have to calculate and explicitly set the constant, which will also have to be re-calculated any time the frame changes. Using the scroll view's `.heightAnchor.constraint`,  setting it equal to the `.heightAnchor` of the view, and setting `multiplier: 0.5` gets you 50% without any calculations.

So, lots to understand and lots to think about. I've made some edits to your original code. This should be considered a "starting point" for you to learn from, not "drop-in finished code":

```
class CinemaViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        sv.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        sv.zoomScale = sv.minimumZoomScale
        sv.isScrollEnabled = true
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sv
    }()

    let cinema: CinemaView = {
        let v = CinemaView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set our background to yellow, so we can see where it is
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // create 2 "SeatView" objects
        let seat1 = SeatView()
        seat1.isVacant = false
        seat1.seatNumber = "2A"

        let seat2 = SeatView()
        seat2.isVacant = true
        seat2.seatNumber = "3B"

        // set the array of "seats" in the cinema view object
        cinema.seats = [seat1, seat2]

        // assign scroll view delegate
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // set scroll view background color, so we can see it
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .blue

        // add the scroll view to this view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // pin scrollView to top, leading and trailing, with 8-pt padding
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        // set scrollView height to 50% of view height
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

        // add cinema view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(cinema)

        // pin cinema to top and leading of scrollView, with 8.0-pt padding
        cinema.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        cinema.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true

        // set the width of cinema to scrollView width -16.0 (leaves 8.0-pts on each side)
        cinema.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true

        // cinema height set to constant of 60.0 (for now)
        cinema.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true

        // in order to use a scroll view, its .contentSize must be defined
        // so, use the trailing and bottom anchor constraints of cinema to define the .contentSize
        cinema.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        cinema.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    }

}

//At my custom cinemaView
class CinemaView: UIView {

    // when the seats property is set,
    //  remove any existing seat views
    //  and add a new seat view for each seat
    // Note: eventually, this will likely be done with Stack Views and / or constraints
    //       rather than calculated Rects
    var seats = [SeatView]() {
        didSet {
            for v in self.subviews {
                v.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            var seatRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
            for seat in seats {
                self.addSubview(seat)
                seat.frame = seatRect
                seatRect.origin.x += seatRect.size.width + 8
            }
        }
    }

    // we're not doing anything on init() - yet...
    //  un-comment the following if you need to add setup code
    //  see the similar functionality in SeatView class
    /*
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    */

    // perform any common setup tasks here
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        //
    }

}

//At my custom seatView
class SeatView: UIView {

    // change the background color when .isVacant property is set
    var isVacant: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isVacant {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }

    // not used currently
    var seatNumber: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    // perform any common setup tasks here
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. For some reason the `cinemaView.backgroundColor` did get invoked. I tried invoking this in other places like in the CinemaView and in the ViewControllers but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `frames` while creating any `UIView`.

`override init(frame: CGRect)` will be called when you specify the frame of your custom `UIView`.

I have created a similar hierarchy as yours as an example. Have a look at it.

Also `xPos` must be such that it does not overlap the previous `SeatView`, i.e `(new xPos + previous SeatView width)`.

Also in your `SeatView` and `CinemaView` you are adding a `UIView` inside another `UIView` which is kind of redundant. You don't need to do that.

**Example:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let seat1 = SeatView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

        let seat2 = SeatView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

        let cinema = CinemaView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        cinema.seats = [seat1, seat2]

        self.view.addSubview(cinema)
    }
}

class CinemaView: UIView
{
    var seats = [SeatView](){
        didSet{
            for seat in seats
            {
                seat.frame.origin.x = xPos
                xPos += 100
                self.addSubview(seat)
            }
        }
    }
    var xPos: CGFloat = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class SeatView: UIView
{
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```